# Glide & Picasso not loading cloudfront URLs over wifi connection

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, picasso, android-glide

Glide and Picasso working fine in my mobile internet connection. But when I connect my mobile with other mobile hotspot it is not working.If you have doubt you can check my URLs:

1. https://d1qm53daoujrb6.cloudfront.net/1000x923.jpg
2. https://d1qm53daoujrb6.cloudfront.net/1604x1920.jpg
3. https://d1qm53daoujrb6.cloudfront.net/car3x2.jpg

You can test my URLs all are working well and they all are CDN means faster than normal URL.

**Devices I have faced the issue :**

1. OPPO A15 hotspot: Image is loading after 30 sec. I mean when I open the app initially the connectivity speed is 0.00kb/s-20kb/s after 30 second the connection speed goes upto 5mbps and loads all the iamges. You may say this is because of list of iamges,but no the laoding works well in my mobile data connection. [Sample Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj1N0EsGpvI)
2. POCO F3 hotspot: Same with this the net speed initially stays at 10kbps and after 30 second the speed goes upto 5-6mbps and loads all the iamges.
3. VIVO Y19 hotspot: This works well as I expected. Loads Image instantly.
4. VIVO Y11 hotspot: This works well as I expected. Loads Image instantly.

And yes when I connect my laptop with the above hotspots the app works well in android studio emulators.

**But when I load random URLs from google like https://robbreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/The_25_Fastest_Production_Cars_Lead.jpg?w=1000 this loads well in all the above hotspots. As well as Instagram & Youtube work very well in all the above hotspots.** [Speed test sample video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/18hw0C5lGEo)

I don't know whether it is URL issue or Glide/Picasso issue or moblie Hotspot. But I'm sure this is not a Internet Service Provider issue. Because the same ISP is present in both working and not working conditon.

**I'm so stressed in this new year, please help.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this?

```
   Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://d1qm53daoujrb6.cloudfront.net/car3x2.jpg")
        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
        .centerCrop()
        .into(activityMainBinding.loadImg)
```

Comment: I solved this issue by turning off ipv6 in cdn settings